# Malloc on a Pointer Parameter Failing

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scope, malloc

I have the following lines of code:

```
struct c_obj_thing *object = NULL;
c_obj_initalizer(object);
// at this point, (object == NULL) is 'true'
printf("Value: %d\n", object->value); // this segfaults
```

Here is the definition for c_obj_initalizer:

```
int c_obj_initalizer(struct c_obj_thing *objParam) {
  objParam = malloc(sizeof(struct c_obj_thing));
  objParam->pointerThing = NULL;
  objParam->value = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the malloc in the c_obj_initalizer method not stay attached to the pointer passed as a parameter when the method returns?  It seems like the call to the initalizer doesn't do anything.  I realize that passing an actual c_obj_thing not as a pointer would mean that the changes made in the initalizer did not return, but I thought that dynamic memory perpetuated throughout the entire program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you call a function it is sending a copy of the pointer, when you change it in the function you don't change in the calling method. You need to malloc it before initializer.

For example:

```
struct c_obj_thing *object = malloc(sizeof(struct c_obj_thing));
c_obj_initalizer(object);
printf("Value: %d\n", object->value); // this segfaults


int c_obj_initalizer(struct c_obj_thing *objParam) {  
  objParam->pointerThing = NULL;
  objParam->value = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see!  Malloc only assigns the local pointer copy to point to the new memory.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you need for some reason do the allocation in the function `c_obj_initalizer`, you have to pass pointer to pointer to that function:

```
int c_obj_initalizer(struct c_obj_thing ** objParam) {
  *objParam = malloc(sizeof(struct c_obj_thing));
  *objParam->pointerThing = NULL;
  *objParam->value = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

and than call like this:

```
struct c_obj_thing *object = NULL;
c_obj_initalizer(&object);
```

Comment: Although this is syntactically correct, I would avoid doing this, sending a double pointer only for the reason of being able to malloc it inside a function is a bad programming practice. You have all the extra dereferences and you have to free it down the road, which may be hard to follow if you're initializing multiple objects.

Comment: @drew I agree with your point on question "who is the owner of the object", but sometimes you need to do that like this (because of inherited design) and stick to some kind of conventions to decide who is the owner.